# Docker multistage build error c# (v20.10.8)

Tags: c#, docker, entity-framework-core, multistage

I have a microservice project and it includes docker. I am using .Net and .Net Framework. .Net 5.0 and .Net Framework 4.7.2
I don't get an error while building the project, but when I need to upload it to docker, I get an error. What is the solution ?

```
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/Customers/Wise.Customers/Wise.Customers.csproj", 
"Services/Customers/Wise.Customers/"]
COPY ["Services/Customers/Wise.Customers.Application/Wise.Customers.Application.csproj", 
"Services/Customers/Wise.Customers.Application/"]
COPY ["Services/Customers/Wise.Customers.Domain/Wise.Customers.Domain.csproj", 
"Services/Customers/Wise.Customers.Domain/"]
COPY ["Services/Wise.Core/Wise.Core.csproj", "Services/Wise.Core/"]
COPY ["Services/Customers/Wise.Customers.Infrastructure/Wise.Customers.Infrastructure.csproj", 
"Services/Customers/Wise.Customers.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Customers/Wise.Customers/Wise.Customers.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Customers/Wise.Customers"
RUN dotnet build "Wise.Customers.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Wise.Customers.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Wise.Customers.dll"]
```

error;
[image]

Comment: please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, [not as screenshot](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). also: .net _framework_ (before core) doesn't run on linux-docker containers. you either have to port it, or use a windows-docker container (with all its restrictions)

Comment: The error you show is a build error but you say you don't get build errors? Anyway, the error you get is because you're building a Linux image and .NET Framework is Windows only.